# import Spacy on RPI in Pycharm and other IDE gives error

Tags: python, python-3

I successfully installed Spacy using `pip install spacy` and alternatively through Pycharms virtual env, but when I `import spacy` in my program it's giving me the following error;

```
    home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python /home/pi/PycharmProjects/testSpeech/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/PycharmProjects/testSpeech/main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import spacy
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from thinc.neural.util import prefer_gpu, require_gpu
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ._classes.model import Model  # noqa: F401
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 11, in <module>
    from ..train import Trainer
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/train.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .optimizers import Adam, linear_decay
  File "thinc/neural/optimizers.pyx", line 14, in init thinc.neural.optimizers
  File "thinc/neural/ops.pyx", line 36, in init thinc.neural.ops
  File "/home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blis/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cy import init
ImportError: /home/pi/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/blis/cy.cpython-37m-arm-linux-gnueabihf.so: undefined symbol: __atomic_load_8

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Use 'pip3 install spacy' for Python3

Answer (score 2):

With `pip` and `python` you have installed the Python version 2 of `spacy`. This isn't supported any longer, and it's not surprising that you have problems. Use Python version 3:

```
pip3 install spacy
```